# How to replace escaped slashes via mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm migrating an old web server with an strange php script for directory browsing to an apache httpd server with the standard directory browsing.
The old script required urls like http://myserver/index.php?fm_dir=dir1%2Fsubdir1%2Fsubdir2
This should be replaced now by an url like http://myserver/dir1/subdir1/subdir2

For an easy migration I try to rewrite the url via mod rewrite.

I tried already the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fm\_dir\=(.*)$
RewriteRule index\.php$ /%1? [R]
```

But the escaped slashes are still escaped and I get and 404 (http://myserver/dir1%2Fsubdir1%2Fsubdir2).

Could someone give me a hint how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fm\_dir\=(.*)$
RewriteRule index\.php$ /%1? [NE,N]

# as long as there are two or more slashes, 
# replace only one and keep looping internally
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%2F(.*)\%2F(.*) $1/$2\%2F$3 [NE,N]

# when there is only one left, 
# replace that last one and send redirect to the client
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%2F(.*) $1/$2 [L,R=302]
```